# App icon height and width issue

Tags: android, android-icons

I have been developing apps from the last 3 years, i have placed app icon of exact 72x72 and 48x48 into mdpi and hdpi folders

but still it does not cover the full width and height of the app icon on the screen,
any one guide me what could be the issue(see screenshot with white area around app icon)

any help would be appreciated.

[image: eastsider app icon]

Comment: Are you willing to make the white surrounding disappear ?

Comment: seems like you are not using a .png with transparent background

Comment: yes i want to remove that white surrounding, that's right :)

Comment: i am using PNG its confirmed and i have tried to use two three different app icons but still issue is there..

Comment: you need to place your icon on a transparent background.

Comment: its in transparent background man..

Comment: upload the source of your icon and paste the link here

Comment: thank you guys, i finally solved it and posted my answer below, it might help any one else in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all helping me in this issue:

finally i resolved this issue myself:

actually my app icon was in resolutions 48x48 and 72x72  with transparent background but still it was showing white line around it.

looking into this issue in more detail i got to know that there was 2-3 pixel transparent gap in that icon around it and android was rendering it like a white background around it.

expanding image 100% left,right,top & bottom resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

the icon should be a png with transparency.

it looks like your icon has a white background.